# Hide and unhide rows dependent upon pull down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, data-validation

I have a Cell (D3) with a pull down menu of 8 items (all words). Dependent upon the pull down item selected, I want to hide, all other rows without that specific word in column K (11 columns over from the start).

I also need an option to show all rows if "All Rows" if that is selected from the pull down menu.

Any ideas on the VBA to relate to the pull down menu cell value ?

Also, How do I relate the VBA code to the pull down menu when selected ?

Thank you and I appreciate any help.

Does this code look correct ?
Sub PhaseTargettoStart()

Dim rMyCell As Range
    Set rMyCell = Range("D3")
 BeginRow = 6
    EndRow = 301
    ChkCol = 10
    If Range("Audit!D3") = "Source Selection" Then
    Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

```
Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "Source Selection + 4 weeks" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "Step 5 + 8 weeks" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "TKO" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "OTOP" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "VP" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "Process Audit" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "PDR" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "PS" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Else
If Range("Audit!D3") = "Show All" Then
Rows("6:301").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When formatting your dropdown menu, you specify a cell to hold the result of the item that was chosen in the menu.

This is called the "cell link" and it will always contain a *number* equal to the position of the user's choice in the dropdown menu list.

You can use INDEX() to get the actual value of the menu item (from the list of menu items), and [this tutorial page](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/hide-unhide-rows-worksheet/#bm1) shows how to hide/unhide rows with VBA.

I'm going to get you started on this, but this site is not a "code it for me site". You have to invest the time to learn how to code in VBA.

First, you have to set up your dropdown list correctly.  In the picture below, I have set up some data similar to yours with a dropdown list (also known as a combo box).

[image]

Here, I have formatted the control and defined the Input Range (list items) as A2:A8 and the Cell Link as B2.  When I select "Show All" from the dropdown, cell B2 shows 7, because "Show All" is the 7th item in the list.

Now, your assignment is to make a similar dropdown list and assign this macro to it:

```
Sub ShowHideRows()
'Set up variables
Dim ResultText As String
        
'Initialize variables
'If choice is "Show All", set ResultText to ABCD, a value that won't be found
'Otherwise, get the text from the list
If Range("B2") = 7 Then
    ResultText = "ABCD"
Else
    ResultText = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A2:A7"), Range("B2"))
End If

MsgBox (ResultText)
        
End Sub
```

If you do everything correctly, then whenever you select an item from the list, you should see a message displaying the list item that you picked.

If you have to learn more about how to write and debug VBA, or how to assign a VBA module to a control, then use the internet and research how to do those things.

Ask questions here if you run into problems.

Comment: Does this code look correct ?

Comment: No.  There are several things wrong here.  You should do this with a loop, not a bunch of nested If...Then statements. And your cell link can't be the cell where your dropbox is.  First, format your dropbox by CTRL-clicking on it and choose "Format Control..."  In that dialog, specify a cell to hold the output of your dropbox.  Say you choose your cell link to be in A1, and the list of menu items is in B1:B10.  More coming...