# Need a formula to display only certain rows based on dropdown selction

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I am trying to figure out a formula that displays only rows based on the scenario selected in dropdown D3. I do not want to use the sort filters. If I select Scenario 0, only rows that have Scenario 0 in them should show, if I select Scenario 1, only rows that have Scenario 1 in them should be listed. My sheet is rather wide as well, and contains numbers and text across A:DS. Not sure if that matters or not? My sheet is confidential, so I cannot post the original. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What did you try? Keep in mind that this is not a script writing service. The intent of SU is to help you with a specific problem. Try something, see where you get stuck, then ask the question based on where you got stuck. Also you couldn't see the image because you don't have enough reputation yet. I have embedded it for you

Comment: And showing/hiding rows using formulas is not possible.

Comment: Show / hiding rows can only be done through VBA

Comment: Thank you. I do not expect anyone to write a code for me. I have tried various combinations of IF and LOOKUP functions. If this cannot be done I do not see any need to waste anyone's time. Thanks!

Comment: It would be fairly easy to attach a VBA macro to your dropdown box.  A [very similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1239991/hide-and-unhide-rows-dependent-upon-pull-down-list/1240013#1240013) was answered here recently.  I gave the author enough information to get started on a solution to his problem, and yours is very similar.  That fellow never returned, so maybe I made it sound too daunting. :-) But you have figured out how to format the dropdown box correctly, and you would only need 10 or so lines of code to show/hide the rows you want.  In fact, ...

Comment: ...I already wrote it for the other guy, and I'd be happy to walk you through how to do it.